# how to do post request if there is multiple image to be sent with other data

Tags: flutter

#I am trying to sent my data through rest api all my data seem to be sent accept for my image

```
   static Future<String> postHomework(String classId,String sectionId,String subjectId,String homeWorkTitle,String link,String homeworkDetail, List<XFile> homeworkImage,String submissionDate,BuildContext context) async{
       String userData;
       String token;
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       userData = prefs.getString("userData");
       if(userData!=null){
         token = json.decode(userData)['token'];
       }else{
        return null;
       }
      http.MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest("POST",Uri.parse("Api goes here"));
      Map<String,String> headers = {"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data",'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'};
      var bytes = await Future.wait(homeworkImage.map((image) =>image.readAsBytes()));
      request.files.addAll(bytes.map((b) =>http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', b)));
      request.headers.addAll(headers);
       request.fields['classid'] = classId;
       request.fields['subjectid'] =subjectId;
       request.fields['content'] = homeworkDetail;
       request.fields['title'] = homeWorkTitle;
       request.fields['submission_date'] = submissionDate;
       request.fields['section_id'] = sectionId;
       http.StreamedResponse responseAttachmentSTR = await request.send();
       final reqAttachment = request.files.length;
       if(responseAttachmentSTR.statusCode == 200){
         print(reqAttachment);
         Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("Homework-section-subject-list");
       }
       print(responseAttachmentSTR.statusCode);
       return "SENT";
  }
```

## the problem is i am not able to send the images i picked from my gallery to server

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://axiftaj.medium.com/how-to-upload-multiple-images-to-server-in-flutter-by-using-http-package-8993f71a1b72) out.
I think you have to listen to the response like this :

```
response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
    print(value);
});
```

Comment: also tried it but no luck the thing is in my server i have to show list of image in this way inside Form Data there is fields to show image in this way file[0]:(binary) file[1]:(binary) classid: kkoi, subjectid:ssio, title:some title here everything goes accept for these image which should be inside file[0] file[1].......